# How is A= UL different from A = LU

Tags: linear-algebra

Using Guassian elimination introducing zeros into the columns of $A$ in the
order, $n: - 1:2$ and producing the factorization $A = UL$ where $U$ is unit upper triangular and $L$ is lower triangular. How is this different from $A = LU.$ Can I relate the two procedures?

Comment: Does "unit upper triangular" mean "ones on the diagonal"?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 } = 
\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\
0 & 1}
\pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\
1 & 1} \\
\pmatrix{
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 } = 
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\
1 & 1}
\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\
0 & -1}
$$
So evidently the two approaches produce different results.

One (weak) relation is that if you start with 
$$
A  = L U
$$
and transpose everything, you get 
$$
A^t = U^t L^t
$$
and because $U^t$ is lower-triangular, and $L^t$ is upper triangular, you get
$$
A^t = L' U',
$$
but this time $L'$ has the ones on the diagonal rather than $U$ having ones on the diagonal. I guess that's really a relationship between two different versions of LU factorization, rather than one being UL factorization.

Comment: Transpose shuffles upper/lowerness, but inverse preserves it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $$A = LU$$

then (assuming $A^{-1}$ exists.) :

$$A^{-1} = U^{-1}L^{-1}$$
 We can verify this by hand if you don't believe it.

What remains is to show that $U^{-1}$ is also upper triangular and $L^{-1}$ is also lower triangular if $U,L$ are, respectively.